# Jquery FullCalendar Extend Start Date or End Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using Jquery FullCalendar.

Here is the link of calender I am using : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I have a case where I have startdate and enddate.

Now if I extend startdate or enddate by dragging it.

How can I get the response event that was triggered when I dragged/extend the date?

**For Example:**

When I **move** the event from one date to another I use **eventDrop**. It gives me the days added or subtracted to the original dates.

I need the same solution for extending startdate or enddate.

**Possibilities I am facing:**

Original Dates : 2013-12-04 to 2013-12-07

When Extends   : 2013-12-04 to 2013-12-10

OR

When Extends  : 2013-12-01 to 2013-12-07

Here are the cases I am facing. How can I track that what event I performed in Calender and what parameters it pass ?

Comment: you can use `eventResizeStart` , `eventResizeStop` , `eventResize` when you extend the `end date` , and `dragStart` and `dragStop` for changing the `start date`

Comment: Can I check that if my Event is on single date ( I mean no end date, just start date ), so in that case it should not be resizable. How can I do that ?

Comment: ou can restrict that using `eventDurationEditable` http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDurationEditable/

Answer (score 4):

You can use **eventResize**

below is the example from offical site:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        // events here
    ],
    editable: true,
    eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {

        alert(
            "The end date of " + event.title + "has been moved " +
            dayDelta + " days and " +
            minuteDelta + " minutes."
        );

        if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
            revertFunc();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Can I check that if my Event is on single date ( I mean no end date, just start date ), so in that case it should not be resizable. How can I do that ?

Comment: [Event_Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)  . You can add property durationEditable:false to a single Event which not allowing it be editable through resizing.

Comment: Can we do the same for 2 dates event ? Like an event having both start and end dates, should not be allowed to resize to single date.

Comment: sure, you can add above property to any single Event. Furthermore you can add eventDurationEditable:false while initializing fullCalendar to prohibit all resizing action.

Comment: This option is locking resize on doubles dates event too

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Fullcalender is providing alot of options where you play around wth your events , as per you requirement

`Original Dates : 2013-12-04 to 2013-12-07`

`When Extends : 2013-12-04 to 2013-12-10`

This is when you extend the event duration, to catch the event where you change the end date you can use the below code

```
eventResizeStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log('RESIZE START ' + event.title);

},
eventResizeStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log('RESIZE STOP ' + event.title);

},
eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log('RESIZE!! ' + event.title);
    console.log(dayDelta + ' days'); //this will give the number of days you extended the event
    console.log(minuteDelta + ' minutes');

},
```

`Original Dates : 2013-12-04 to 2013-12-07`

`When Extends : 2013-12-01 to 2013-12-07`

This is when you pre-pone the event , then you can use the below code

```
eventDragStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log('DRAG START ' + event.title);
    console.log(this);
},
eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log('DRAG STOP ' + event.title);
    console.log(this);
},
eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    console.log('DROP ' + event.title);
    console.log(dayDelta + ' days'); //this will give the number of days you dragged before or after
    console.log(minuteDelta + ' minutes');
    console.log('allday: ' + allDay);

},
```

As per you comment above that if you want to restrict the user from dragging a event or resizing a event , then you can use `eventDurationEditable` , this is `true` by default

`eventDurationEditable:false,`